# C# ImageConverter conversion problems

Tags: c#, image

Im trying to send images over HTTP using HttpListener but some images come from program resources and when converting them to byte array, size just drops (original image in resources is: 301,046 bytes and when converted its only 67,098 bytes big)

```
public byte[] Buffer = (byte[])new 
    ImageConverter().ConvertTo(global::TestProject.Properties.Resources.sowy, 
    typeof(byte[]));
```

Due to that bug some images don't aper in web-browser.

Comment: Did you test the code without the HTTP environment?

Comment: You should not directly instantiate `TypeConverter` derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i solved it by converting image to mobile device (using Photoshop, png format)